# PHP copy() from NFS results in trash at end of file

Tags: php, ftp, copy, nfs, openvms

Situation:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- PHP 7
- NFS share from an OpenVMS host

Trying to copy a file from the NFS share to a local directory.

The PHP `copy()` function copies the file, but the resulting local file has a bunch of junk at the end of it. I suspect it's the allocated but unused area at the end of the physical OpenVMS file, but haven't proved that.

Using `copy( 'ftp://...' )` results in

> failed to open stream: FTP server reports 502 SIZE is unimplemented

`file_put_contents( ..., file_get_contents( ... ))` **does** work, though.

Can somebody please explain to me why `file_get_contents()` gets the correct data and copy() does not?

Comment: Have you tried the ftp functions PHP has? They're a bit more precise than trying to open a socket. My bet is the junk characters are control commands being written into the stream as part of the FTP process

Comment: I AM using the PHP functions. The copy() function, specifically.

Comment: I'm talking about functions like [ftp_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php)

Comment: NFS or FTP? Post contains both but not clear how it is related.

Comment: Do you get the error message and broken content?

Comment: copy( '/mnt/shareName/filename', 'destFilePath') results in broken content. copy( 'ftp://...filename', 'destFilePath') results in error.